# How to switch scala versions in console with alias (MacOS)?

Tags: macos, scala, alias

It was easy to do with java versions (example: `export JAVA_8_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v1.8.0_232`)). Any way to do the same with scala?

Comment: How do you execute Scala? If via SBT, the Scala version to use is specified in the build definition (and even gets downloaded automatically). If running an executable jar, the Scala library is already included in there. If run via `java -cp somewhere/scala-lib.jar`, the classpath points at the Scala version. Not sure in which scenario you'd want an environment variable. Especially since you cannot switch between 2.11.x, 2.12.x, 2.13.x at runtime (i.e. without also recompiling the application).

Comment: @Thilo i have legacy project, that works only with 2.9 version(build with maven). Now i have only 2.12 executable scala in my console, so i need to switch to 2.9. Am i right in thinking or there is another way to compile it?

Comment: How do you run/compile your project? Do you use SBT (was that even a thing back then...)

Comment: @Thilo i compile it with maven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used **SDKMAN**. With `sdk install scala` it will install the latest scala. You can manually download any version that you need from [here](https://www.scala-lang.org/). Then move your folder to `/Users/{username}/.sdkman/candidates/scala` (your destination file should be named as version like 2.x.x). After that open .bash_profile and use 
alias scalaX='sdk default scala X.X.X' (X - your version)